# average length of characters mysql compared to length of name

Tags: mysql, database, compare, average, string-length

I need to compare the average length of the column name to each name and if the name had more characters, I need to show that name...
Can anyone help me?

```
WHERE length(naam) > sum(length(naam)/count(naam);
WHERE length(naam) > (sum(length(naam)/count(naam));
WHERE length(naam) > avg(length(naam)
```

The above didn't work, but maybe it gives you an idea of a possible solution

Comment: Are you looking for values inside of a given column 'naam' which are longer than the average length of that column?   I'm having trouble distinguishing between you talking about the column 's own name and the values held within the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery which returns the average length of the column name in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE length(naam) > (SELECT AVG(length(naam)) FROM tablename);
```